# React - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

In this simple React App, I don't understand why I get the following warning message:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

To me it seems that I put the key at the right place, in form of **key={item.login.uuid}**

How can I get rid of the warning message?
Where would be the right place to put the key?

***App.js***

```
import UserList from './List'

const App = props => {
  const [id, newID] = useState(null)
  return (
    <>
      <UserList id={id} setID={newID} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

***List.js***

```
const UserList = ({ id, setID }) => {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([])

  const fetchResource = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.randomuser.me'
    )
    setResources(response.data.results)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResource()
  }, [])

  const renderItem = (item, newID) => {

    return (
      <>
        {newID ? (
          // User view
          <div key={item.login.uuid}>
            <div>
              <h2>
                {item.name.first} {item.name.last}
              </h2>
              <p>
                {item.phone}
                <br />
                {item.email}
              </p>
              <button onClick={() => setID(null)}>
                Back to the list
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          // List view
          <li key={item.login.uuid}>
            <div>
              <h2>
                {item.name.first} {item.name.last}
              </h2>
              <button onClick={() => setID(item.login.uuid)}>
                Details
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        )}
      </>
    )
  }

  const user = resources.find(user => user.login.uuid === id)

  if (user) {
    // User view
    return <div>{renderItem(user, true)}</div>
  } else {
    // List view
    return (
      <ul>
        {resources.map(user => renderItem(user, false))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default UserList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `key` needs to be on the root-level element within the loop. In your case, that's the fragment (`<>`).

To be able to do that, you'll need to write it out fully:

```
const renderItem = (item, newID) => {

  return (
    <Fragment key={item.login.uuid}>
      {newID ? (
        ...
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

(You can add `Fragment` to your other imports from `react`).

Note that the fragment isn't actually needed in your example, you could drop it and keep the `key`s where they are since then the `<div>` and `<li>` would be the root element:

```
const renderItem = (item, newId) => {

  return newID ? (
    <div key={item.login.uuid}>
      ...
    </div>
  ) : (
    <li  key={item.login.uuid}>
      ...
    </li>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you create 2 separate components, one for the user view and one for the list item. That way you only need to pass the user prop. Also, use JSX and pass wht key from there.

```
const UserList = ({ id, setID }) => {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([])

  const fetchResource = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.randomuser.me'
    )
    setResources(response.data.results)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResource()
  }, [])

  const User = ({user}) => (
    <div key={user.login.uuid}>
      <div>
        <h2>
          {user.name.first} {user.name.last}
        </h2>
        <p>
          {user.phone}
          <br />
          {user.email}
        </p>
        <button onClick={() => setID(null)}>
          Back to the list
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

  const ListItem = ({user}) => (
    <li key={user.login.uuid}>
      <div>
        <h2>
          {user.name.first} {user.name.last}
        </h2>
        <button onClick={() => setID(user.login.uuid)}>
          Details
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  )

  const user = resources.find(user => user.login.uuid === id)

  if (user) {
    // User view
    return <User user={user}</div>
  } else {
    // List view
    return (
      <ul>
        {resources.map((user, index) => <ListItem key={index} user={user} />)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default UserList
```